# MySQL 8/Node Connector API: Table is undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using MySQL 8 and the [Node connector API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en) to update a record and return whether the result was successful or not.

I'm following the docs and these [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/tutorial-Working_with_Tables.html) but they're not enitrely helpful or in depth when it comes to code examples.

The current error I'm getting is:

```
database Error in database.confirmEmail ReferenceError: table is not defined
    at session.getSchema.getTable.update.where.bind.set.execute.then (C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\src\database.js:95:25)
```

Here is my code below:

```
exports.confirmEmail = (token, email) =>
    session
      .then(session => 
        session
          .getSchema(config.schema)
            .getTable('users')
            .update()
            .where('validation_code = :token')
            .bind('token', token)
            .set('is_confirmed', 1)
            .execute()
            .then(() => table)
      )
      .then(table => {
        let results = []
        return table
          .select('is_confirmed')
          .where('validation_code = :token & email = :email')
          .bind('token', token)
          .bind('email', email)
          .execute(doc => results.push(doc))
      })
      .catch(e => debug('Error in database.confirmEmail', e))
```

Why is `table` undefined?

Comment: line 12? maybe `.then(table => table)`?

Comment: No that's not the issue. The docs give an example the same way I used it too.

Comment: It has something to do with the binding because I manually do: `.where('validation_code = "oe461g"')` it works and updates the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are partially incorrect. You need to assign something to the `table` variable. I guess you want something like:

```
const table = session.getSchema(config.schema).getTable('users')

return table.update()
  .where('validation_code = :token')
  .bind('token', token)
  .set('is_confirmed', 1)
  .execute()
  .then(() => table)
```

Disclaimer: I'm the connector lead dev.

Comment: Yes, we keep the docs in the source tree and we accept pull requests as long as the contributor signs the Oracle Contribution Agreement (OCA).